# Simple jpa question

Tags: java, orm, jpa

I have to go through some code of a project to implement some missiong functionality.
It uses jpa.In some popj classes i have found

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TYPE")
@NamedQueries( { 
 @NamedQuery(name = "getTypes", query = "SELECT dct FROM Type dct") 
})
```

I know that i can used to get all records by using this query.Does this query return all records in type table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return **all** the `Type` entities including subtypes, if any. And since I can't say if this there are any subtypes, I can't say if this query will be restricted to the `TYPE` table.

Comment: hm, good point. I didn't assume inheritance, because there is no `@Inheritance` or `@MappedSuperclass`, but it's not impossible to have some hierarchy.

Comment: @Bozho Yeah, the class could be part of a hierarchy so I just made the answer generic, just in case. But the OP should provide the class definition for such questions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it does. It generates an SQL query that looks roughly like this:

```
SELECT [column list here] FROM type
```